# How to import Ext Js library in Odoo?

Tags: extjs, odoo

How do I link Odoo and Ext Js library in order to use some web controls from Ext Js in Odoo module?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Opoo is a ERP.

B) ExtJS creates a webpage.

If you use Sencha Tooling (Sencha CMD) you can create a folder containing the `index.html` file and the app.js (plus css files). You get this by typing `sencha app build` and you can find the result inside the build folder.

If you link Opoo to the index.html you are good to go.